# SSRS Subreport disappears after page is changed

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with SSDT(SQL Server Data Tools) and "Microsoft Reporting Services Projects" to create a SSRS Report. In this Report I have several Subreports to show detail information.

It can happen that one of the subreports shows no additional data. In this case I still want the structure of the Subreport to be shown, like this (table structure with thinner Bordes is the Subreport):

[image]

But when I switch to another page and back to this page of the Report, the structure is gone:

[image]

This seems to be the case, when there is no information in the Subreport.
There are no visibility properties set, neither in the Subreport nor in the "parent"-Report, so everything should be visible all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will happen because your sub report does not return anything and hence the blank.
For Testing just try running one of your sub report only (without main report) with parameter which does not return data and you will see your sub report page is completely empty

Now how to solve this issue:

For your sub report:

I would add static table (without datasets) and add it on top of your tablix.

I will add visibility rule to this static table to show only when your datasets does not return data. so that this static is visible only when original subreport data is not available, else you have your subreport data been shown.

Comment: The Tablix I use in the Subreport doesn`t refer to a Dataset directly

Comment: what does that mean? how are you getting your data then?

Comment: The structure of the table is fully hardcoded. The textboxes in the table get their data from a dataset, but the table itself isn't connected directly.
The textboxe value is set by: 'Sum(Fields!lField1.Value, "dsName")'

Answer (score 0):

This happend because SSRS think should hide the subreport since all the dataset are empty (or the only one you have) so to avoid that in your subreport just add a new dataset with
'select 1 as one'
that will do the job